# OpenBSD, NVIDIA, and Xorg

Tags: xorg, openbsd, nvidia

I've installed OpenBSD 5.2 i386 on my desktop however I hit a wall when it came to running X at my native resolution (1920x1200). All of the hardware is working normally except for the video card: an NVIDIA Geforce 560 TI. I don't need 3D support or anything special from the card, just native resolution for doing work.

It is my understanding that these cards are supported by the `nv` driver, however being a newer card, `nv` doesn't pick up on it and defaults to `vesa` which doesn't have widescreen support.

Here's my `xrandr` output:

```
$ xrandr                                                                                                                                                        
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1600 x 1200, maximum 1600 x 1200
default connected 1600x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200       0.0* 
   1280x1024       0.0  
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

Here's the relevant portion of my `dmesg`:

```
pci0 at mainbus0 bus 0: configuration mode 1 (bios)
pchb0 at pci0 dev 0 function 0 "Intel 82G33 Host" rev 0x02
ppb0 at pci0 dev 1 function 0 "Intel 82G33 PCIE" rev 0x02: apic 2 int 16
pci1 at ppb0 bus 1
vga1 at pci1 dev 0 function 0 vendor "NVIDIA", unknown product 0x1200 rev 0xa1
wsdisplay0 at vga1 mux 1: console (80x25, vt100 emulation)
wsdisplay0: screen 1-5 added (80x25, vt100 emulation)
azalia0 at pci1 dev 0 function 1 vendor "NVIDIA", unknown product 0x0e0c rev 0xa1: msi
azalia0: no supported codecs
```

The [manual](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq11.html#ConfigX) recommends generating a new `xorg.conf` by running `X --configure` as root, but it fails with a segfault:

```
... loading modules, etc ...
[    94.206] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for dummy
[    94.206] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for glint
[    94.211] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for i128
[    94.211] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for i740
[    94.211] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for neomagic
[    94.211] (II) NV: driver for NVIDIA chipsets: RIVA 128, RIVA TNT, RIVA TNT2,
    Unknown TNT2, Vanta, RIVA TNT2 Ultra, RIVA TNT2 Model 64,
    Aladdin TNT2, GeForce 256, GeForce DDR, Quadro, GeForce2 MX/MX 400,
    GeForce2 MX 100/200, GeForce2 Go, Quadro2 MXR/EX/Go,
    GeForce2 Integrated GPU, GeForce2 GTS, GeForce2 Ti, GeForce2 Ultra,
    Quadro2 Pro, GeForce4 MX 460, GeForce4 MX 440, GeForce4 MX 420,
    GeForce4 MX 440-SE, GeForce4 440 Go, GeForce4 420 Go,
    GeForce4 420 Go 32M, GeForce4 460 Go, Quadro4 550 XGL,
    GeForce4 440 Go 64M, Quadro NVS, Quadro4 500 GoGL,
    GeForce4 410 Go 16M, GeForce4 MX 440 with AGP8X,
    GeForce4 MX 440SE with AGP8X, GeForce4 MX 420 with AGP8X,
    GeForce4 MX 4000, GeForce4 448 Go, GeForce4 488 Go, Quadro4 580 XGL,
    Quadro4 NVS 280 SD, Quadro4 380 XGL, Quadro NVS 50 PCI,
    GeForce4 448 Go, GeForce4 MX Integrated GPU, GeForce3,
    GeForce3 Ti 200, GeForce3 Ti 500, Quadro DCC, GeForce4 Ti 4600,
    GeForce4 Ti 4400, GeForce4 Ti 4200, Quadro4 900 XGL, Quadro4 750 XGL,
    Quadro4 700 XGL, GeForce4 Ti 4800, GeForce4 Ti 4200 with AGP8X,
    GeForce4 Ti 4800 SE, GeForce4 4200 Go, Quadro4 700 GoGL,
    Quadro4 980 XGL, Quadro4 780 XGL, GeForce FX 5800 Ultra,
    GeForce FX 5800, Quadro FX 2000, Quadro FX 1000,
    GeForce FX 5600 Ultra, GeForce FX 5600, GeForce FX 5600XT,
    GeForce FX Go5600, GeForce FX Go5650, Quadro FX Go700,
    GeForce FX 5200, GeForce FX 5200 Ultra, GeForce FX 5200,
    GeForce FX 5200LE, GeForce FX Go5200, GeForce FX Go5250,
    GeForce FX 5500, GeForce FX 5100, GeForce FX Go5200 32M/64M,
    Quadro NVS 55/280 PCI, Quadro FX 500/600 PCI,
    GeForce FX Go53xx Series, GeForce FX Go5100, GeForce FX 5900 Ultra,
    GeForce FX 5900, GeForce FX 5900XT, GeForce FX 5950 Ultra,
    GeForce FX 5900ZT, Quadro FX 3000, Quadro FX 700,
    GeForce FX 5700 Ultra, GeForce FX 5700, GeForce FX 5700LE,
    GeForce FX 5700VE, GeForce FX Go5700, GeForce FX Go5700,
    Quadro FX Go1000, Quadro FX 1100, GeForce 6800 Ultra, GeForce 6800,
    GeForce 6800 LE, GeForce 6800 XE, GeForce 6800 XT, GeForce 6800 GT,
    GeForce 6800 GT, GeForce 6800 GS, GeForce 6800 XT, Quadro FX 4000,
    GeForce 6800 GS, GeForce 6800, GeForce 6800 LE, GeForce 6800 XT,
    GeForce Go 6800, GeForce Go 6800 Ultra, Quadro FX Go1400,
    Quadro FX 3450/4000 SDI, Quadro FX 1400, GeForce 6600 GT,
    GeForce 6600, GeForce 6600 LE, GeForce 6600 VE, GeForce Go 6600,
    GeForce 6610 XL, GeForce Go 6600 TE/6200 TE, GeForce 6700 XL,
    GeForce Go 6600, GeForce Go 6600 GT, Quadro NVS 440, Quadro FX 550,
    Quadro FX 550, Quadro FX 540, GeForce 6200, GeForce 6500,
    GeForce 6200 TurboCache(TM), GeForce 6200SE TurboCache(TM),
    GeForce 6200 LE, GeForce Go 6200, Quadro NVS 285, GeForce Go 6400,
    GeForce Go 6200, GeForce Go 6400, GeForce 6250, GeForce 7100 GS,
    GeForce 6800, GeForce 6800 LE, GeForce 6800 GT, GeForce 6800 XT,
    GeForce 6200, GeForce 6200 A-LE, GeForce 7800 GTX, GeForce 7800 GTX,
    GeForce 7800 GT, GeForce 7800 GS, GeForce 7800 SLI, GeForce Go 7800,
    GeForce Go 7800 GTX, Quadro FX 4500, GeForce 7350 LE,
    GeForce 7300 LE, GeForce 7300 SE, GeForce Go 7200, GeForce Go 7300,
    GeForce Go 7400, GeForce Go 7400 GS, Quadro NVS 110M,
    Quadro NVS 120M, Quadro FX 350M, GeForce 7500 LE, Quadro FX 350,
    GeForce 7300 GS, GeForce 7650 GS, GeForce 7600 GT, GeForce 7600 GS,
    GeForce 7300 GT, GeForce 7600 LE, GeForce 7300 GT, GeForce Go 7700,
    GeForce Go 7600, GeForce Go 7600 GT, Quadro NVS 300M,
    GeForce Go 7900 SE, Quadro FX 550M, Quadro FX 560, GeForce 7900 GTX,
    GeForce 7900 GT, GeForce 7900 GS, GeForce 7950 GX2, GeForce 7950 GX2,
    GeForce 7950 GT, GeForce Go 7950 GTX, GeForce Go 7900 GS,
    GeForce Go 7900 GTX, Quadro FX 2500M, Quadro FX 1500M,
    Quadro FX 5500, Quadro FX 3500, Quadro FX 1500, Quadro FX 4500 X2,
    GeForce 6150, GeForce 6150 LE, GeForce 6100, GeForce Go 6150,
    Quadro NVS 210S / NVIDIA GeForce 6150LE, GeForce Go 6100,
    GeForce 6150SE, GeForce 6100 nForce 405, GeForce 6100 nForce 400,
    GeForce 6100 nForce 420, GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M,
    GeForce 7000M / nForce 610M, GeForce 7050 PV / nForce 630a,
    GeForce 7050 PV / nForce 630a, GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a,
    GeForce 8800 GTX, GeForce 8800 GTS, GeForce 8800 Ultra,
    Quadro FX 5600, Quadro FX 4600, GeForce 8600 GTS, GeForce 8600 GT,
    GeForce 8600 GT, GeForce 8600 GS, GeForce 8400 GS, GeForce 9500M GS,
    GeForce 8300 GS, GeForce 8600M GT, GeForce 9650M GS,
    GeForce 8700M GT, Quadro FX 370, Quadro NVS 320M, Quadro FX 570M,
    Quadro FX 1600M, Quadro FX 570, Quadro FX 1700, GeForce GT 330,
    GeForce 8400 SE, GeForce 8500 GT, GeForce 8400 GS, GeForce 8300 GS,
    GeForce 8400 GS, GeForce 8600M GS, GeForce 8400M GT,
    GeForce 8400M GS, GeForce 8400M G, Quadro NVS 140M, Quadro NVS 130M,
    Quadro NVS 135M, GeForce 9400 GT, Quadro FX 360M, GeForce 9300M G,
    Quadro NVS 290, GeForce GTX 295, GeForce GTX 280, GeForce GTX 260,
    GeForce GTX 285, GeForce GTX 275, GeForce GTX 260, GeForce GTX 295,
    Quadroplex 2200 D2, Quadroplex 2200 S4, Quadro CX, Quadro FX 5800,
    Quadro FX 4800, Quadro FX 3800, GeForce 8800 GTS 512,
    GeForce 9800 GT, GeForce 8800 GT, GeForce GT 230, GeForce 9800 GX2,
    GeForce 9800 GT, GeForce 8800 GS, GeForce GTS 240, GeForce 9800M GTX,
    GeForce 8800M GTS, GeForce GTX 280M, GeForce 9800M GT,
    GeForce 8800M GTX, GeForce 8800 GS, GeForce GTX 285M,
    GeForce 9600 GSO, GeForce 8800 GT, GeForce 9800 GTX/9800 GTX+,
    GeForce 9800 GTX+, GeForce 9800 GT, GeForce GTS 250,
    GeForce 9800M GTX, GeForce GTX 260M, Quadro FX 4700 X2,
    Quadro FX 3700, Quadro VX 200, Quadro FX 3600M, Quadro FX 2800M,
    Quadro FX 3700M, Quadro FX 3800M, GeForce 9600 GT, GeForce 9600 GS,
    GeForce 9600 GSO 512, GeForce GT 130, GeForce GT 140,
    GeForce 9800M GTS, GeForce 9700M GTS, GeForce 9800M GS,
    GeForce 9800M GTS, GeForce 9600 GT, GeForce 9600 GT,
    GeForce GTS 160M, GeForce GTS 150M, GeForce 9600 GSO,
    GeForce 9600 GT, Quadro FX 1800, Quadro FX 2700M, GeForce 9500 GT,
    GeForce 9400 GT, GeForce 9500 GT, GeForce 9500 GS, GeForce 9500 GS,
    GeForce GT 120, GeForce 9600M GT, GeForce 9600M GS, GeForce 9600M GT,
    GeForce 9700M GT, GeForce 9500M G, GeForce 9650M GT, GeForce G 110M,
    GeForce GT 130M, GeForce GT 120M, GeForce GT 220M, GeForce 9650 S,
    Quadro FX 380, Quadro FX 580, Quadro FX 1700M, GeForce 9400 GT,
    Quadro FX 770M, GeForce 9300 GE, GeForce 9300 GS, GeForce 8400,
    GeForce 8400 SE, GeForce 8400 GS, GeForce 9300M GS, GeForce G100,
    GeForce 9300 SE, GeForce 9200M GS, GeForce 9300M GS, Quadro NVS 150M,
    Quadro NVS 160M, GeForce G 105M, GeForce G 103M, GeForce G105M,
    Quadro NVS 420, Quadro FX 370 LP, Quadro NVS 450, Quadro FX 370M,
    Quadro NVS 295, GeForce 9100M G, GeForce 8200M G, GeForce 9200,
    GeForce 9100, GeForce 8300, GeForce 8200, nForce 730a, GeForce 9200,
    nForce 980a/780a SLI, nForce 750a SLI, GeForce 8100 / nForce 720a,
    GeForce 9400, GeForce 9400, GeForce 9400M G, GeForce 9400M,
    GeForce 9300, ION, GeForce 9400M G, GeForce 9400, nForce 760i SLI,
    GeForce 9400, GeForce 9300 / nForce 730i, GeForce 9200,
    GeForce 9100M G, GeForce 8200M G, GeForce 9400M, GeForce 9200,
    GeForce G102M, GeForce G102M, ION, ION, GeForce 9400, ION, ION LE,
    ION LE, GeForce GT 220, GeForce 315, GeForce 210, GeForce GT 230M,
    GeForce GT 330M, GeForce GT 230M, GeForce GT 330M, NVS 5100M,
    GeForce GT 320M, GeForce GT 240M, GeForce GT 325M, Quadro FX 880M,
    GeForce G210, GeForce 205, GeForce 310, ION, GeForce 210,
    GeForce 310, GeForce 315, GeForce G105M, GeForce G105M, NVS 2100M,
    NVS 3100M, GeForce 305M, ION, GeForce 310M, GeForce 305M,
    GeForce 310M, GeForce 305M, GeForce G210M, GeForce 310M,
    Quadro FX 380 LP, Quadro FX 380M, GeForce GT 330, GeForce GT 320,
    GeForce GT 240, GeForce GT 340, GeForce GT 330, GeForce GTS 260M,
    GeForce GTS 250M, GeForce 315, GeForce GT 335M, GeForce GTS 350M,
    GeForce GTS 360M, Quadro FX 1800M
[    94.213] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for s3
[    94.213] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for s3virge
[    94.213] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for siliconmotion
[    94.213] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for sis
[    94.213] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for trident
[    94.213] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for wsudl
[    94.213] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    94.269] (EE) Unable to locate/open config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
[    94.269] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/X11R6/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    94.269] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    94.269] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    94.269] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    94.269] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    94.270] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    94.270] (==) Disabling SIGIO handlers for input devices
[    94.270] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    94.270] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    94.270] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/,
    /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/,
    /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/
[    94.270] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/X11R6/lib/modules"
[    94.270] (II) The server relies on wscons to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure wscons or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    94.270] Segmentation fault at address 0x14
[    94.270] 
Fatal server error:
[    94.270] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    94.270] 
[    94.270] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    94.270] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    94.270] 
[    94.271] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Without `X --configure` working, I'm not sure how else to get a valid `xorg.conf`. X is running right now but even so it doesn't keep a copy of it's configuration anywhere that I'm aware of (I looked with `find`).

I did manage to get a promising looking modeline:

```
Modeline "1920x1200"x0.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz eP)
```

... but it isn't using it automatically and it otherwise goes in `xorg.conf` which I'm not able to generate.

Any suggestions or pointers would be really appreciated, I've been Googling similar issues for a while and am coming up short of a good "next step".

Comment: The same here buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to break it to you, but the nv driver does not support your card. Nvidia stopped updating this driver a few years ago, so there is currently no way to get native resolution on OpenBSD with recent Nvidia cards.

This may change in the future though. The ttm memory manager is being ported to FreeBSD, which in turn makes it easier to port to OpenBSD. Once this is done, porting the nouveau driver should be "relatively" easy.